# how to group by nested properties using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class Split
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sort> Sorts { get; set; }
    public double Mass { get; set; }
}
public class Sort
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Fraction> Fractions { get; set; }
}
public class Fraction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Method Method { get; set; }
}
public class Method
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get something like the following selection/grouping of Splits for all Methods:

`{Id, Mass, MethodCode}`.  It's fine for `split` to repeat for example:

```
1, 4.4, "Samm"
1, 4.4, "Mani"
2, 2.1, "Samm"
3, 1.5, "Pra"
```

In the end, I want to be able to take this list and ask something like: give me splits such that their method is "samm".  If you can suggest a better structure, it's also fine. I will fetch this from SQL server, so I am looking for the most performant structure.

Comment: Which `Id` do you want.  I'm guessing it's `Split.Id`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And I don't see any obvious aggregates, so what you do mean by grouping?

Comment: @ESG This actually looks like they want to do the opposite of grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `Sort` or `Fraction` but here's how you can get those values from that structure where `splits` is an `IEnumerable<Split>`.

```
var result = from s in splits
             from r in s.Sorts
             from f in r.Fractions
             select new 
             {
                 s.Id,
                 s.Mass,
                 f.Method.Code
             };
```

Or in method syntax

```
var result = splits.SelectMany(
    s => s.Sorts.SelectMany(
        r => r.Fractions.Select(
            f => new
            {
                s.Id,
                s.Mass,
                f.Method.Code
            })));
```